# Laravel routing system

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-4

I am working with laravel 4 and i have a problem with my routes,

for example :

```
//Route to display a campaign
Route::get('campaigns/{name}', 'CampaignController@show');

//Route to create a campaign
Route::get('campaigns/add', 'CampaignController@create');
```

The problem here is : the routing system thinks that the **add** in `campaigns/add` is a **campaign name** so it takes me to `campaigns/{name}`

How can i fix it ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: but what if the campaign is called add?! thanks obama

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel matches routes from the top down. So all you need to do is put 'campaigns/add' above the wildcard route.