# Laravel advanced routing system

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to implement a simple CMS with Laravel 5.2 which basically handles two kinds of routes. The first one is used to browse a website view, that has to be `{view}.html`. The controller iterates the database records and if it can't find that page, will return a 404 error page:

```
Route::get('/{page}', [
    'as' => 'page',
    'uses' => 'Website\WebsiteController@showPage'
])->where(['page' => '.+(\.html)']);
```

For example these routes will match:

```
www.mydomain.ext/homepage.html
www.mydomain.ext/about.html
www.mydomain.ext/news.html
www.mydomain.ext/contact.html
```

and so on. The second one is a route group for the admin control panel:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => env('ADMIN_PREFIX', 'admin'),
    'as' => env('ADMIN_PREFIX', 'admin') . '::',
    'middleware' => ['auth']
        ], function() {

    /*
     * ADMIN ROUTES
     */
});
```

So all the routes in this group will be something like:

```
www.mydomain.ext/admin/dashboard
www.mydomain.ext/admin/user/1
www.mydomain.ext/admin/page/2
```

and so on.

From what I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21999268/2343305):

> Laravel matches routes from the top down. So all you need to do is put 'campaigns/add' above the wildcard route.

And that's what I've done:

**routes.php**

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => Localization::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect'] 
     // LaravelLocalization (https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)
        ], function() {

    Route::auth();

    // admin routes    
    Route::group([
        'prefix' => env('ADMIN_PREFIX', 'admin'),
        'as' => env('ADMIN_PREFIX', 'admin') . '::',
        'middleware' => ['auth']
            ], function() {

        /*
         * ADMIN ROUTES
         */
    });

    Route::get('/{page}', [
        'as' => 'page',
        'uses' => 'Website\WebsiteController@showPage'
    ])->where(['page' => '.+(\.html)']);
});
```

But when I try to call an admin route, Laravel throws this error:

```
 Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\Website\Core\WebsiteCoreController::showPage()
```

So I suppose I'm doing something wrong... Any suggestions on how to fix my code?

Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: What url are you using? Also, your showPage function has $page parameter? `public function showPage($page)` ?

Comment: Yes, I have the $page parameter. When The user logs in it's redirected to `/admin/dashboard` so the complete URL is, for example, `http://localhost/mycms/public/{locale}/admin/dashboard`

Comment: Don't you need to put this route `Route::get('/{page}', [` inside admin route groups?

Comment: No @FelippeDuarte that route is used for the website navigation... I'll edit my question so you can better understand